# Pinescript profit taking and stop strategy.exit function executing outside of allowed trade time set in script

Tags: datetime, pine-script

I've been coding a take profit/SL script to help me build a strategy I am using. I do have one issue where I want to limit the take profit and stop loss to only trigger within a certain timeframe i.e. do not trigger between 0400-0700. I am using this on the 1 hr chart. If conditions are met and still true at 0700 then fire then. I have this set up appropriately for my entry and exit conditions outside of the take profit and stop loss and it works great. I created a time condition for the take profit and stop loss and it seems to work almost all the time but there are a few times where it still alerts between 0400-0700. Is there something I am missing that is special that needs to be done to accomplish this? Any help is appreciated! Example code below

```
//@version=5
strategy("TEST", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity,
         default_qty_value = 100,
         initial_capital = 50000,
         max_labels_count = 300)

// --- Input parameters ---
var longTrailPerc = 2 * 0.01

// --- Time range filter ---
timeAllowed = input.session("0600-1900", "Allowed hours")
timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":1234567")
timeAllowed2 = input.session("0600-1500", "Allowed hours")
timeIsAllowed2 = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed2 + ":1234567")


// === INPUT BACKTEST RANGE ===
i_from = input.time(defval = timestamp("20 Jun 2021 00:00 +0000"), title = "From")
i_thru = input.time(defval = timestamp("01 Mar 2025 00:00 +0000"), title = "Thru")

// === INPUT SHOW PLOT ===
i_show = input     (defval = true, title = "Show Date Range")

// === FUNCTION EXAMPLE ===
date() => time >= i_from and time <= i_thru  // create date function "within window of time"

// --- Entry and exit conditions ---
long_condition = close > ta.ema(close,9) and date()
exit_condition =  close < ta.ema(close,18) and date()

tradeOpenPL() =>
    sumProfit = 0.0
    for tradeNo = 0 to strategy.opentrades - 1
        sumProfit += strategy.opentrades.profit(tradeNo)
    result = sumProfit

// Determine trail stop loss prices
longStopPrice = 0.0

longStopPrice := if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    stopValue = close * (1 - longTrailPerc)
    math.max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
else
    0

// --- Strategy execution ---
if long_condition and strategy.position_size == 0 and timeIsAllowed
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)  
if  exit_condition and strategy.position_size > 0 and timeIsAllowed 
    strategy.close("Long", comment = "Exit1",qty = strategy.position_size)

percentAsPoints(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? (pcnt / 100 * strategy.position_avg_price / syminfo.mintick) : float(na)

if strategy.position_size > 0 and timeIsAllowed2
    strategy.exit("PT1", qty_percent = 30, profit = percentAsPoints(2), stop = longStopPrice, alert_profit = "PT1", alert_loss = "TRLSTP")
    strategy.exit("PT2", qty_percent = 30, profit = percentAsPoints(3), stop = longStopPrice, alert_profit = "PT2", alert_loss = "TRLSTP")
    strategy.exit("PT3", qty_percent = 30, profit = percentAsPoints(4), stop = longStopPrice, alert_profit = "PT3", alert_loss = "TRLSTP")
    strategy.exit("TRLSTP", profit = percentAsPoints(100), stop = longStopPrice, alert_loss = "TRLSTP")`
```

`
I tried limiting the time allowed for the profit taking and stop loss but doesn't seem to work like it does for entries/exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exit orders will stay in the order book. It is not like you call `strategy.exit()` conditionally and that exit order will work for that bar only.

You need to use `strategy.cancel()` to cancel your exit order when you go out of your allowed time zone.

> It is a command to cancel/deactivate pending orders by referencing
> their names, which were generated by the functions: strategy.order,
> strategy.entry and strategy.exit.

```
strategy.cancel(id) → void
```

Comment: Thank you!! this worked perfectly. Makes complete sense and was driving me crazy. I appreciate it.